Get all transactions from/to a Gnosis address
I need to track all coin movements to/from a wallet.
I use the account:tokentx Gnosisscan API endpoint. It returns a list of transactions concerning ERC20 tokens.
But how can I obtain the list of transactions concerning:

xDai
other non-ERC20 "coins" if such things exist.

FWIW:

I am not interested in NFT tokens.
I am not specifically attached to Gnosisscan. If more straightforward solutions exist, I am open to consider them.
I am a seasoned programmer, but new to the web3 ecosystem.


Hope my answer helps!

Based on my experience, the simplest way to approach this is with Alchemy, however currently the Gnosis chain is not supported by the Alchemy SDK.

Basically, all coin tokens share the same event names that they emit: e.g. no matter whether it's a an ERC777 or an ERC223 token, they still emit the Transfer event (in most cases):
As per the ERC777 token specification:

send(address recipient, uint256 amount, bytes data) public See
IERC777.send.
Also emits a IERC20.Transfer event for ERC20 compatibility.

As per the ERC223 token specification:

Events
Transfer event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed
_to, uint256 _value, bytes _data)
Triggered when tokens are transferred.
Compatible with and similar to the ERC-20 Transfer event.

For instance, here's a random ERC777 token (caution: the token itself is just for reference, it might be malicious, I just picked it for reference, as there's a decent list of events on that contract!): (https://gnosisscan.io/tx/0xa512c7e9ca9a5529f0e28638a6aac880e2f5ef97108bb96dc87742fca06e04f9#eventlog)

GET https://api.gnosisscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&address=0x5fF1958268D15872659d3D58B692AD68468B5fc3&page=1&offset=10&startblock=34911430&endblock=34911435&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken


You'll see both the ERC777 and the ERC20 tokens in the returned response.


So the aggregator API doesn't really care whether the coin token is a standard or a non-standard one, it will return all the transactions that include an emitted "Transfer" event. So the method tokentx pretty much suits for any semi-compliant coin tokens that emit the Transfer event on transfers, just like ERC20 does per standard.

However, to get the list of all of the incoming and outcoming transfers of the native xDai token, you only have the option of requesting the Gnosis API explicitly with a new type tag, i.e. txlistinternal, e.g.:
GET https://api.gnosisscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlistinternal&address=0x3cC47c557E985Cb8b52d1E263a1296fd2097121c&page=1&offset=100&startblock=0&endblock=9999999999&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

As far as I researched, there's no way to do a batch-call to get all of the coin transfers and native xDai transfers at the same time.
You can see the list of all incoming/outcoming Gnosis native currency transactions, XDai:


So as the solution, you can get these separately, and then concatenate the two response arrays, and, if needed, sort them chronolgically, whether in an ascending or a descending order.
So just doing the calls one-by-one, and then merging the two arrays together is probably the most efficient solution.

P.S. With Alchemy, there's a way to do a batch call to get multiple types of transaction at one batch call, but unfortunately the Alchemy API and the Alchemy SDK do not support the Gnosis chain at the moment.
Still, if you ever need it, the solution to getting all semi-ERC20 coin tokens and native coin transactions EITHER TO OR FROM ONLY A SPECIFIC ADDRESS with only one batch call using Alchemy is the following:
// Setup: npm install alchemy-sdk
import { Alchemy, Network } from "alchemy-sdk";

const config = {
  apiKey: "<-- ALCHEMY APP API KEY -->",
  network: Network.ETH_MAINNET,
};
const alchemy = new Alchemy(config);

const data = await alchemy.core.getAssetTransfers({
  fromBlock: "0x0",
  fromAddress: "0x5c43B1eD97e52d009611D89b74fA829FE4ac56b1",
  // or to address: toAddress: "0x5c43B1eD97e52d009611D89b74fA829FE4ac56b1",
  category: ["internal", "erc20"],
});

console.log(data);

So there're caveats to using this Alchemy solution too, because if you specify both the toAddress and fromAddress that are equal, you'll literally get the from<->to transactions only, e.g. if Alice sends tokens to herself (aj Alice -> Alice transfer).

Finally, you can use Infura and track the transactions yourself using on-chain filters, but this will require a WebSocket server, and saving the data somewhere in your own DB for further reference, which of course is a much more complex solution than merging two arrays together with code. :)

Thanks for this very detailed answer, @Mila. I came to the conclusion that using Gnosiscan, I have to use 3 API calls:  account:tokentx, account:txlistinternal, and account:txlist. I will take a look at Alchemy when I will have the time;)

Glad it was helpful, @SylvainLeroux!! :) Please also accept my answer :)
